# Stretch UILabel to full width of UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

This sounds like a trivial thing to do, but for some reason I can't figure out how to get this work with AutoLayout.

I have a UICollectionViewCell with two subviews in Interface Builder

```
UICollectionViewCell
  - UILabel
  - UILabel
```

The UICollectionViewCell has a dynamic width height, and so I'd like to set the first UILabel's frame to be something like this using AutoLayout.

```
CGRectMake(5, 5, collectionViewCell width, collectionViewCell height-10);
```

However if I select UICollectionViewCell and UILabel, and then click the left-most icon to "Add new alignment constraints", then none of the options are available (e.g. Trailing Edges).

Answer (score 1):

Those menu items were not enabled, because the two items you selected did not have a common superview.

Select `UILabel` without also selecting `UICollectionViewCell`.

Auto Layout already understands that the cell is the label's superview, and knows to pin the label's edges to the cell.

**Update:**

- The 'Pin' tool is used for size, or spacing between items.  In your
  case, you want to set the space between your label and the cell.
- The 'Align' tool is used for centering items, or lining items up by
  an edge. For example, if you had two labels in your cell, you could
  ensure that one label lined up with the other label's baseline.

Comment: None of the "Add new alignment constraints" are available even if I only select one label.

Comment: You need to use the 'Pin' (middle) icon to pin the label to the cell's `contentView`.  (The alignment icon would align the label with a sibling control.)